# Trouble facing while using Azure AD B2C for authentication

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to authenticate my web application with Azure AD B2C with specifications shared in the site: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started

After following that guide to the code and logging in, I am getting the message:

> "We can't seem to find your account".

Do I need to customize any other settings in policies or application settings?

Comment: Can you include more details such as the actual code you're using, the settings (you can anonymize it), screenshot of the error? Otherwise it's hard to help you.

Comment: sure, will be updating soon.

Comment: Hi, i could see the trouble cause is because the the logged in user is in guest mode. If we are about to signup and create a new user, it will work out.

Comment: Great! Can you please add an answer to your question with your findings and flag the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a user via the Azure Portal we have a "Guest Users", with the Source "Azure Active Directory", when creating a non-account.com user. 
When inheriting a user via the Azure Portal we are creating a "Member", with the Source "External Azure Active Directory" when creating a non-account.com user.
When creating a user via the SignUp we are creating a "Member", with the Source "Azure Active Directory". 
So for the "Guest User" this will fail since it is a "Guest User" and not a "Member" 
...and it will fail for the inherited user it will fail since that member belongs to an "External Azure Active Directory"

The User type always need to be "Member" and have the Source "Azure Active Directory"